# JWT login does not work despite successful Registration

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, jwt, authorization

I'm having an issue with authentication in my first JwtSecurity application. User registration works fine, and accessing secured endpoints with a token is also successful. However, the 'authenticate'(login) operation always results in a 403 Forbidden error. I'm unsure how to proceed. I'm using Spring Boot version 3.0.10. Here are snippets of my code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

@PostMapping("/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(
        @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request
) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.authenticate(request));
}
```

```
private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
    authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    request.getEmail(),
                    request.getPassword()
            )
    );
    var user = userRepository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found"));
    var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
    return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
            .token(jwtToken)
            .build();
}
```

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config)  throws Exception  {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

   @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
```

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail= jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if(userEmail!=null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null){
            UserDetails userDetails =  this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt,userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```
private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
           .csrf()
           .disable()
           .authorizeHttpRequests()
           .requestMatchers("api/v1/auth/**")
           .permitAll()
           .anyRequest()
           .authenticated()
           .and()
           .sessionManagement()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
           .and()
           .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
           .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
```

I followed an Amigoscode JWT authorization tutorial, and I've double-checked my implementation, but I'm still facing an issue. I can't find the problem despite comparing it with the tutorial and searching online. Can you help me, please

Comment: I also used the same tutorial to create my application but I used the 'lambda method' to configure the securityFilterChain function, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to enable CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing). Do this by adding it to your filterchain method

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that i gave and nothing change